# geolocation　現在地変更 monaca

Tags: monaca

現在　MONACAを使いアプリ開発をしております。　geolocationで現在地を取得したり、目的地を指定したりはできるのですが、端末の現在地情報を書き換えることはできますでしょうか？つまり現在地の置き換えです。現在地を変更し、違うアプリから位置情報を確認したいです。やり方をご存知の方はご教授頂けると助かります、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

GPS情報を偽装したいってことですよね？

先に回答から言いますと「Monacaだけを使用してGPSを偽装することは出来ません」

以下、作成にあたって疑問点だらけなのですが……
`Monaca`で実装するとなると`Cordovaプラグイン`を使用しなければなりません。
`Cordovaプラグイン`が使用できるプランに加入していますか？
また、ザックリGPSを偽装するプラグインについて調べましたが、
該当する`Cordovaプラグイン`は既存の物がないように思われます。
ですので、ご自身で作成することになるかと思いますが、その際`JAVA`や`Swift`で開発します。
関連タグに`JAVA`や`Swift`などが入っておりませんが作成する予定はありますか？
他、作成するにあたって対象とするOSとOSバージョンはいくつですか？
OSとバージョンによっては開発すら出来ないものもあります。

開発中のみ偽装したいのであれば
Androidなら既存のアプリで位置情報を偽装するアプリがあります。
iOSの場合は脱獄しないと位置情報は偽装出来なかったと思います。
(一部OSは`com.apple.Maps.plist`を編集することでシミュレートできた話を聞いたことがありますが…)